# How to detect if a Unicode char is supported by EBCDIC in .NET 4.0?

Tags: unicode, .net-4.0, ebcdic

We have a web site and WinForms application written in .NET 4.0 that allows users to enter any Unicode char (pretty standard).

The problem is that a small amount of our data gets submitted to an old mainframe application.  While we were testing a user entered a name with characters that ending up crashing the mainframe program.  The name was BOËNS.  The E is not supported.

What is the best way to detect if a unicode char is supported by EBCDIC?

I tried using the following regular expression but that restricted some standard special chars (/, _, :) which are fine for the mainframe.

I would prefer to use one method to validate each char or have a method that you just passed in a string and it returned true or false if chars not supported by EBCDIC were contained in the strig.

Answer (score 1):

First, you would have to get the proper [Encoding instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) for EBCDIC, calling the static [`GetEncoding` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzsz3bk3.aspx) which will takes the code page id as a parameter.

Once you have that, you can set the [`DecoderFallback` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.decoderfallback.aspx) to the value in the [static `ExceptionFallback` property on the `DecoderFallback` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.decoderfallback.exceptionfallback.aspx).

Then, in your code, you would loop through each character in your string and call the [`GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5881c0k9.aspx) method to encode the character to the byte sequence.  If it cannot be encoded, then a [`DecoderFallbackException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.decoderfallbackexception.aspx) is thrown; you would just have to wrap each call to `GetBytes` in a `try/catch` block to determine which character is in error.

Note, the above is required if you want to know the position of the character that failed.  If you don't care about the position of the character, just if the string will not encode as a whole, then you can just call the [`GetBytes` method which takes a string parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55.aspx) and it will throw the same `DecoderFallbackException` if a character that cannot be encoded is encountered.

Comment: Ok... now the simple one... Where is the Encoding instance for EBCDIC?

Comment: There is no .NET encoding instance for EBCDIC.

Comment: @Jim Mischel @xanatos: No, there is not, EBCDIC is a code page.  That is why I linked to the `GetEncoding` method that takes a code page as a parameter (there is a list of the code pages with code page ids for over 30 EBCDIC code pages).

Comment: Sorry. That comment was directed at xanatos. I should have included a clarification (or reiteration) of what you said about getting an encoding for a code page.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape characters in Regex using the `\` . So if you want to match a dot, you can do `@"\."` . To match `/._,:[]-` for example: `@"[/._,:\-\[\]]`  . Now, EBDIC is 8 bits, but many characters are control characters. Do you have a list of "valid" characters?

I have made this pattern:

```
string pattern = @"[^a-zA-Z0-9 ¢.<(+&!$*);¬/|,%_>?`:#@'=~{}\-\\" + '"' + "]";
```

It should find "illegal" characters. If `IsMatch` then there is a problem.

I have used this: http://nemesis.lonestar.org/reference/telecom/codes/ebcdic.html

Note the special handling of the `"`. I'm using the `@` at the beginning of the string to disable `\ escape expansion`, so I can't escape the closing quote, and so I add it to the pattern in the end.

To test it:

```
Regex rx = new Regex(pattern);
bool m1 = rx.IsMatch(@"a-zA-Z0-9 ¢.<(+&!$*);¬/|,%_>?`:#@'=~{}\-\\" + '"');
bool m2 = rx.IsMatch(@"€a-zA-Z0-9 ¢.<(+&!$*);¬/|,%_>?`:#@'=~{}\-\\" + '"');
```

`m1` is `false` (it's the list of all the "good" characters), `m2` is `true` (to the other list I've added the `€` symbol)